# unable to install Photoshop on ubuntu

Tags: wine, photoshop

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and latest wine from Ubuntu software center, when I try to install Photoshop CS6 using wine I receive an error.

I checked the `Allow Executing File As Program` in Photoshop Setup(`setup.exe`) and tried `More troubleshooting tips:` in the error message.

Error Message:

```
Installation Failed

Your installation encounter Errors

**Installer failed to initialize. This Could be due to a missing file.**

More troubleshooting tips:
1. Restart your computer:
2. Exit all application including startup items, virus checking and firewall software.
3. launch the installer and reinstall your application.
```

Answer (score 8):

Step 1. Install the Wine Team Ubuntu PPA

By installing the Wine Team Ubuntu PPA, we can ensure the version of wine we’re using is suitable and up to date.

To install the wine team PPA, execute the following, one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

Step 2. Using winetricks to get install dependencies for Photoshop CS6

Now that we have the most recent build of wine, we can get started on fetching the necessary build packages to run the Photoshop installer.

Here’s the command to issue and pull those dependencies

```
winetricks atmlib gdiplus msxml3 msxml6 vcrun2005 vcrun2005sp1 vcrun2008 ie6 fontsmooth-rgb gecko
```

If a few errors pop-up, don’t worry – chances are this install will still work.

Step 3. Running the Photoshop CS6 installer

Now that you have all dependencies required to run Photoshop CS6, you can now run the Adobe setup. Either right click Set-up.exe, or from the terminal:

```
cd /home/user/path/to/installer
wine Set-up.exe
```

Source:

[Complete guide to running Photoshop CS6 on Ubuntu 13.10 | Geebzor.com](http://geebzor.com/tech/linux/complete-guide-to-running-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu-13-10/)

Although this is for 13.10 it should work on 14.04 too as long as the Wine version is the same.

Comment: step 1: is completed but i given the command in step 2 i receive the error "Resolving download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com) failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘download.microsoft.com’ 
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/A/F/0AFB5316-3062-494A-AB78-7FB0D4461357/windows6.1-KB976932-X86.exe failed"  then i tried to install photoshop cs6 i receive same problem mentioned in question

Comment: Of course, because the second command is about installing all it's dependencies. Try again or get some help from the WineHQ Forums. They can help you better than I do.

Answer (score 4):

You might wanna try [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/).

it currently supports the following Adobe PhotoShop versions:

- [Adobe Photoshop CS4](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-595-Adobe_Photoshop_CS4.html)
- [Adobe Photoshop CS6](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html).
- [Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-2247-Adobe_Photoshop_Lightroom_5.html)

**PlayOnLinux**:

> PlayOnLinux is a graphical front-end for the [Wine software
>   compatibility layer](https://www.winehq.org/) which aims to simplify the installation of 
>   Windows-based applications and games on Linux and Darwin.

**Install**:

```
wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

---

Press install, search for PhotoShop, and the rest is pretty self explanatory. Due note, that it has been reported that the **portable** version of PhotoShop with POL, works well, and fast.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

 <sup>Screenshot from: [League of Legends under Ubuntu - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/league-of-legends-under-ubuntu)</sup>